# How to make FreeCodeCamp Test Suite work on Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have successfully created markdown-previewer on svelte but whenever I click ‘Run tests’(from CDN: https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js), it logs

[image]

bundle.js:584 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
Is there a way to fix this, so I can proceed.

Or perhaps someway to post my code on codepen and paste the link to see if they can see my html?